# How can I retrieve numeric value from text file in shell script?

Tags: bash

below content has been written in a text file called test.txt. How can I retrieve pending  & completed count value in shell script?

```
<p class="pending">Count: 0</p>
<p class="completed">Count: 0</p>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
echo 'Fetching job page and write to Jobs.txt file...'
curl -o Jobs.txt https://cms.test.com

completestatus=`grep "completed" /home/Jobs.txt | awk -F "<p|< p="">" '{print $2 }' | awk '{print $4 }'`
echo $completestatus
if [ "$completestatus" == 0 ]; then
```

Comment: how to get the completed count?.curl -o Jobs.txt https://test.cmx.com

status=`grep "completed" /home/Jobs.txt

Comment: You call it a 'text' file, but it's trivial to wrap it up as XML, then you'd have a whole suite of more appropriate tools for this sort of query.  Don't be tempted to transform it into to a shell script and `eval` that - it's a recipe for a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` and `awk` commands can almost always be combined into 1 `awk` command. And 2 `awk` commands can almost always be combined to 1 `awk` command also.

This solves your immediate problem (using a little awk type casting trickery).

```
completedStatus=$(echo "<p class="pending">Count: 0</p>^J
      <p class="completed">Count: 0</p>" \
    | awk -F : '/completed/{var=$2+0.0;print var}' )
echo completedStatus=$completedStatus
```

The output is

```
completedStatus=0
```

Note that you can combine `grep` and awk with

```
awk -F : '/completed/' test.txt
```

filters to just the completed line , **output**

```
<p class=completed>Count: 0</p>
```

When I added your `-F` argument, the output didn't change, i.e.

```
  awk -F'<p|< p="">' '/completed/' test.txt
```

**output**

```
<p class=completed>Count: 0</p>
```

So I relied on using `:` as the `-F` (field separator). Now the output is

```
awk -F : '/completed/{print $2}'
```

**output**

```
 0</p>
```

When performing a calculation, `awk` will read a value "looking" for a number at the front, if it finds a number, it will read the data until it finds a non-numeric (or if there is nothing left). So ...

```
  awk -F : '/completed/{var=$2+0.0;print var}' test.txt
```

**output**

```
  0
```

Finally we arrive at the solution above, wrap the code in a **modern** command-substitution, i.e. `$( ... cmds ....)` and send the output to the `completedStatus=` assignment.

---

In case you're thinking that the `+0.0` addition is what is being output, you can change your file to show completed count = 10, and the output will be 10.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
completedStatus=$(awk -F'[ :<]' '/completed/{print $(NF-1)}' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you just want to extract pending or completed and the value. If that is the case,

Then Using SED,

please check out below script.[Output shared via picture, please click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ar6.jpg)

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"

echo "Simple"

cat $1 |sed 's/^.*=\"\([a-z]*\)\">Count: \([0-9]\)<.*$/\1=\2/g'

echo "Pipe Separated"

cat $1 |sed 's/^.*=\"\([a-z]*\)\">Count: \([0-9]\)<.*$/\1|\2/g'

echo "CSV Style or comma separeted"

cat $1 |sed 's/^.*=\"\([a-z]*\)\">Count: \([0-9]\)<.*$/\1,\2/g'
```